# Polymorph methods in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm sure that the code below did work a few weeks ago.

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke]
String Hazaa(TypeUno input);

[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke]
String Hazaa(TypeDuo input);
```

Someone has changed something (possibly me, not that I can think of anything) and now, the service nags about polymorphism. I'm required to add *Name* to the operation contract like so. The call I'm performing is via URL address line and targets an other method, *Ping*, which is on *GET* method base. These two below are *POST*.

```
[OperationContract(Name="Uno")]
[WebInvoke]
String Hazaa(TypeUno input);

[OperationContract(Name="Duo")]
[WebInvoke]
String Hazaa(TypeDuo input);
```

What can have changed?! It's not a big problem to go with names at the moment but still - the testing code (that I know did work) makes a call to the service client with the same name but different input types.

Comment: I'm not sure how you got it to work the first time, but WCF requires unique method names - either using the actual method name or through the `OperationContract.Name` attribute/property.

Comment: Maybe you should check if there is some kind of relation between TypeUno and TypeDuo that could have changed

Comment: @DStanley I know... But I do know that I **never** leave the test cases on fail. These must have worked unless some #¤%& donkey has edited the source code and checked it in without running it.

Comment: @FelipeP Can you elaborate, please? As far I understand, polymorphism is not valid in WCF so what relation could have been deployed before to make it work? I'm buffled.

Comment: So your choices are - keep banging your head against a wall to get it to work or accept the fact that you need unique method manes in WCF.

Comment: @DStanley Yupp. Banged for a while. I think I know who removed the *Name* attribute from the *OperationContract*. He needs to be forgiven, though, because he was very stressed that day. And also because it was me...   :(

Comment: You need to use source control so that you can track changes easily.

Comment: I was linking this to some issues that I have in the past where polimorfism was present between classes, and KnownType attributes where missing, the serializer complained about that